# Ria service generated code not support partial class

Tags: wcf-ria-services, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using Ria service class library. This contains 2 library named `RiaClasslibrary` `RiaClasslibrary.Web`.

`Riaclasslibrary.Web` contains `ADO.NET entity data model` and named `BaseModel`. `BaseModel`contains `tPage` class.

My problem is

I'm inserting separated `tPage` class. This class contains 2 public property. show below

```
public sealed partial class tPage : EntityObject
{        
    public List<tPage> Children { get; set; }
    public tPage Parent { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

After I'm inserting DomainService and building `RiaClasslibrary.Web` class library. But ria service generated code doesn't contains above properties.

You have a question. Why you separate `tPage` class. You simply insert those 3 property in `Modelbase.Designer` code. 
My answer is: Database doesn't contain those 3 property and If I'm inserting properties in the code, properties removed after updating Entity Model.

Answer (score 1):

@ebattulga

I don't know if you still have this issue, but I will post the answer because I came to similar issue.

The answer for

> After I'm inserting DomainService and
>   building RiaClasslibrary.Web class
>   library. But ria service generated
>   code doesn't contains above
>   properties.

is quite easy but hard to find.

You can read here in section "Shared Code" http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-5-Metadata-and-Shared-Classes.aspx

If you want to see custom properties from partial classes on the Client you have to rename class file name from MyClass.cs to simply MyClass.**shared**.cs. This will create partial class in the code generated Client side.

HTH

Daniel Skowroński

Comment: Glad to find your answer, spent hours battling with this problem! +1